# Writing out only part of a log line

Tags: bash, command-line-interface

I want to tail a log, pipe it through grep to find the log entries I am interested in. This is straightforward:

```
tail -f logfile | grep foo
```

But how can I ensure only selected parts of each line are output? Ideally those parts matching a regex.

Comment: You could use the `--only-matching` grep option, for instance

Comment: -o option will do this on any grep from this century.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use `grep -o foo` or `grep --only-matching foo`, where you would expand `foo` to include the entire part of the line that you wanted. The official GNU `grep` manual on this option is [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html#General-Output-Control).